# Excel to csv conversion in java. Problems with currency representation

Tags: java, excel, csv

while converting from excel to csv using the jxl api, I face a problem which is any currency amount greater than 999 is being split into two columns.

i.e $100,000 is split into 100 and 000.

does anyone have a reliable java code that can convert excel to csv without any problems,

regards,

nithen

Answer (score 1):

Enclose the column into quotes otherwise the `,` is treated as a column seperator

```
"$100,000"
```

Comment: You can have a look at Apache POI API.

Comment: @ankit I had used the example given along with apache POI. even there I faced the same problem.

Comment: hi all, this program can reliably batch convert from excel to csv. http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/ss/examples/ToCSV.java